# Переполнение при разложении на простые множители

Tags: c++, простые-числа, overflow, переполнение, факторизация

```
vector<int> fact;
for (int i=2; i*i<=n; ++i)
    if (n % i == 0) {
        fact.push_back(i);
        while (n % i == 0)
            n /= i;
    }
if (n > 1)
    fact.push_back(n);
```

Вот алгоритм разложения числа на простые множители. Может ли тут быть переполнение в `i*i`? И как его избежать, если да?

Comment: Что есть `n`?  *(1 символ нужен...)*

Comment: @Igor число проверяемое типа int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, лучше использовать `unsigned int`, во-вторых - да, может - если у вас `n` - тоже `unsigned int` и представляет собой простое число, большее 4294836225 (говорю о 32-битных числах).

Можно избежать переполнения путем дополнительной проверки, что `i <= 0xFFFF`.

Если `n` имеет тип `int`, то выбор для `i` типа `unsigned int` решает проблему - переполнения не будет.

И можно уменьшить число проверок в 2 раза, если вынести проверку для 2 отдельно, а потом проверять

```
for (int i=3; i*i<=n; i+=2)
```

Comment: Так чтобы переполнения избежать надо увеличить проверки в 2 раза и станет как было :) ?

Comment: Проверки - это в сторону эффективности метода, а не переполнения. Нет смысла в проверке делимости на четные числа, кроме двойки - таких простых чисел не бывает точно...

Comment: Не, я понял. Просто чтобы не было переполнения, как вы говорите, придётся `i <= 0xFFFF` ещё проверять каждый раз. В итоге станет столько же проверок, сколько у меня сейчас.

Comment: Или можно по-другому избежать переполнения, не проверяя каждый раз?

Comment: Ну, можно разово убедиться, что `n` такое, что можно выскочить за пределы, и тогда проверять. И если n уменьшается - то переходить на более эффективную ветку. Можно вычислить sqrt(n), наконец, но это же неспортивно :) Если же `n` типа `int` - можно не беспокоиться, переполнения не будет.

Comment: Казалось бы, один раз вычислить корень будет быстрее, чем много раз делать умножения. Но, померяв на своих данных, оказалось значительно медленнее

Comment: Почему для типа `int` не будет переполнения?

Comment: Потому что для int максимальное положительное значение - 2147483647, так что для `i == 46341` уже будет выход из цикла - а при этом никакого переполнения нет. Только вот диапазон возможных `n` при этом в 2 раза меньше.

Comment: Но ведь при проверке этого значения уже будет переполнение, потому что 46341^2 = 2147488281 > 2147483647

Comment: Так я же говорил, что `i` делаем `unsigned int` - тогда при сравнении *положительное* значение `int n` без изменений перегоняется в `unsigned int` и все получается само собой :)

Comment: Вот, смотрите - https://ideone.com/Gqrf9G

Comment: Всё, понял, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Если предполагается, что n сможет быть велико, проще будет один раз вычислить `sqrt(n)` и сравнивать `i` с ним

Comment: В какую сторону округлять?

Comment: Вверх ... ... ...