# Задача на количество простых делителей. C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, олимпиада, простые-числа, факторизация

Условие [задачи](https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=938):

> Знаете ли вы, что такое простое число? Простое число – это натуральное
> число, имеющее ровно два различных натуральных делителя: единицу и
> самого себя. Все остальные числа, кроме единицы, называются
> составными. Например, числа 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 являются простыми. А числа
> 4, 6, 10 – составными.
>
> Требуется из заданного набора чисел выбрать одно, имеющее максимальное
> количество простых делителей. Например, 30 имеет три простых делителя
> (2, 3 и 5), а 40 – только два (2 и 5).
>
> **Входные данные:** Первая строка входного файла INPUT.TXT содержит число N
> – количество чисел в наборе. Во второй строке теста содержится N
> чисел, разделенных пробелом. Все числа во входных данных целые,
> принимающие значения от 2 до 1024.
>
> **Выходные данные:** В выходной файл OUTPUT.TXT выведите число с
> максимальным количеством простых делителей. Если таких чисел
> несколько, выведите наименьшее из них.

Мое решение:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int cnt_divisors(int n) //по сути задача на факторизацию.
{
    set<int> s; //s - множество для нахождения РАЗЛИЧНЫХ простых делителей (что и требуется по условию задачи)
    for (size_t i = 2; i*i <= n; i++) //факторизуем.
    {
        while (n % i == 0)
        {
            s.insert(i);
            n /= i;
        }
    }
    if (n != 1)
        s.insert(n); //случай простого числа
    return s.size();
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int mxcnt; //число которое мы ищем
    cin >> mxcnt;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) //n - 1 цикл, потому что мы уже сделали ввод в переменную mxcnt
    {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        if (cnt_divisors(x) > cnt_divisors(mxcnt))
            mxcnt = x;
    }
    cout << mxcnt;
}
```

Мое решение проваливается на одном из тестов. На самом деле я реализовывал 3 различных решения и все они проваливаются на одном и том же тесте (что заставляет меня задуматься записывать числа с входа в массив, потому что не исключено, что я мог налажать в реализации "безмассивного" алгоритма). Я не вижу какого-то частного случая? В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: [Пару вопросов назад](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1146662/394322)

Comment: @вася проблема переполнения вроде не затрагивает меня, на входе числа до 1024.

Comment: Там в ответе дан рабочий алгоритм для нахождения простых делителей.

Comment: Вы не выбираете *наименьшее из них*...

Comment: @Harry вы правы. спасибо, сейчас переделаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы выбирать *наименьшее*:

```
    cin >> x;
    if (cnt_divisors(x) > cnt_divisors(mxcnt))
        mxcnt = x;
    else if (cnt_divisors(x) == cnt_divisors(mxcnt) && mxcnt > x)
        mxcnt = x;
```